# What's the difference b/w np.random.randint() and np.random.uniform()?

Tags: python, numpy

What's the difference b/w `np.random.randint()` and `np.random.uniform()`?

I have gone through the numpy documentation but have not gotten a satisfactory understanding of the difference b/w them, except that the default precision of `np.random.uniform()` is much greater than the integer values generated by `np.random.randint()`

Comment: `randint` returns integers. `uniform` returns floating-point numbers.

Comment: Your last sentence is the answer (more or less).

Comment: What exactly is tripping you up? Could you please clarify? The documentation seems pretty clear about what they return, so you have to be very explicitly about what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.random.randint() always returns integer value even when we decide to pick random numbers from a narrow spectrum -

```
>>> print(np.random.randint(2,size=10))
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

At other end, np.random.uniform() always return a unique number (floating numbers) for the same range.

```
>>> print(np.random.uniform(0,1,size=10))
[0.15925408 0.01435238 0.15866946 0.59042522 0.99683699 0.70776862
 0.14471196 0.27948168 0.77953463 0.32399513]
```

Comment: Oh okay. the uniform() method returns unique values. maybe i missed it in the documentation. thanks anyway, this was something that i couldn't really wrap my head around as i thought it to be redundant to have 2 very similar methods.